# How to set up capistrano to cap deploy using perforce as SCM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, perforce

I am new to perforce.  I need to set up capistrano to work with perforce.  I look at the perforce plugin for cap but not quite sure how to set that up.  Any master out there can give me some step by step guide?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing fancy, just set up the required information for your perforce server in your Capfile like so:

```
# Perforce specifics
set :scm, :perforce
set :p4port, "yourserver:1666"
set :p4user, "youruser"
set :p4passwd, "yourpassword"
set :p4, "/usr/local/bin/p4"
set :p4client, "name-of-client-spec"
```

and then set the path to the application in your perforce depot (also in the Capfile):

```
set :application, "Name"
set :repository,  "//depot/path/to/application/...
set :deploy_to, "/path/on/server/to/deploy/to"
```